How can i take a screenshot and Capture Page Screenshot popup message windows and chrome for
I want to write a test script for Robot Framework that allows the Cature system to fill the entire screen including popup messages that notify Windows and Chrome as shown in the image.
I wrote using the Take Screenshot command, but the system still doesn't capture the screen with the popup message.
enter image description here
enter image description here
** Settings **
Library           SeleniumLibrary
Library           ScreenCapLibrary


*** Test Cases ***
TC-01 Invalid Login
    Open Browser To Login Page
    Input Username    ```${WRONG_USERNAME}```
    Input Password    ```${WRONG_PASSWORD}```
    Capture Page Screenshot        
    Submit Credentials
    Verify popup message 
    Take Screenshot        name=screenshot  format=jpg  quality=0


I need some advice on writing Robot Framework test scripts as I have the question above.

I don't know about ScreenCapLibrary - haven't used it, but can guarantee SeleniumLibrary (and similar selenium-based libraries) will not capture that popup - those are part of the OS GUI, a subcomponent of the browser, and are not part of the DOM - so selenium etc do not "see"/screenshot them.

Does it work if you add a delay after Verify popup message keyword?

You can use Capture Page Screenshot keyword which SeleniumLibrary provides. And put a Sleep before capturing the screenshot so the popup is available.
I am unsure about ScreenCapLibrary but if you are using it for screenshot then it is redundant.
Reference :
https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Capture%20Page%20Screenshot
